# convert string to float and align columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, decimal

I have a Dataframe df where a `Date` column belongs to each `Value` column. The contents are (still) formatted as strings:

```
             Date       Value1      Date       Value2
Index      
  0        30.01.2001   20,32     30.05.2005    50,55
  1        30.02.2001   19,5      30.06.2005    49,21
  2        30.03.2001   21,45     30.07.2005    48,1
```

my issues (in order of priority):

1. I do not manage to convert the `Value` columns to float even after I successfully converted the ',' to '.' with

> df.replace(to_replace=",", value='.', inplace=True, regex=True)

so what can you suggest how I can convert to float? I suspect the reason for not working is that there are sometimes only one decimal after the comma. How can I solve this?

2. How can I align the dates so that `Value2`'s dates match those of `Value1` (so it needs to be moved downwards until it matches, provided that the rows continue till the present day)?
3. what is the most efficient way to iterate through the columns in order to do the formatting of the columns?

*EDIT:
Based on the answers so far...how can I iterate through the larger dataframe and split it into single ones/series as suggested? (I have issues adding counter integers to the df's , i.e. df1, df2, df3...)*

Comment: sorry are you saying `df['Value1'].str.replace(',','.').astype(float)` doesn't work?

Comment: exactly, this does not work. I do not get an error while doing so but the conversion does not take effect, @EdChum. dtype is an object and trying to apply functions like mean() result in the error message 'ValueError: could not convert string to float:....'

Comment: Are you assigning back the result? `df['Value1'] = df['Value1'].str.replace(',','.').astype(float)`?

Comment: this is it! this works. Many thanks @EdChum, so part 1. is solved.

Comment: it's a bit weird and problematic to have duplicate column names, you'd be better off renaming them, then convert to `datetime` and self join using `merge`

Comment: I have just received a csv in mentioned fashion. I will try to amend column names and get acquainted with self join.

Answer (score 1):

A number of steps:

```
# I wanted to split into two dataframes
df1 = df.iloc[:, :2].copy()
# rename column to Date because my `read_csv` parsing
df2 = df.iloc[:, 2:].copy().rename(columns={'Date.1': 'Date'})

# As EdChum suggested.
df1.Value1 = df1.Value1.str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
df2.Value2 = df2.Value2.str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)

# Convert to dates
df1.Date = pd.to_datetime(df1.Date.str.replace('.', '/'))
df2.Date = pd.to_datetime(df2.Date.str.replace('.', '/'))

# set dates as index in anticipation for `pd.concat`
df1 = df1.set_index('Date')
df2 = df2.set_index('Date')

# line up dates.
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like a viable solution @piRSquared. I still have to find the most efficient way to apply it to a larger dataframe of thousands of "values"

Comment: how can I iterate through the larger dataframe and split it into single ones/series as suggested? (I have issues adding counter integers to the df's , i.e. df1, df2, df3...)